# XPath expression to find links gives "TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType"

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use scrapy to scrape http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/findlandscaper.htm but I keep getting the error

```
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType
```

I tried looking for similar problems but get no answer to why scrapy is giving me this error.

Here is my spider

```
from scrapy import Spider
from lawn.items import LawnItem
import scrapy
import re 

class LawnSpider(Spider):
    name = "lawn"
    allowed_domains = ['www.lawncaredirectory.com']
    # Defining the list of pages to scrape
    start_urls = ["http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/findlandscaper.htm"] 

    def parse(self, response):
        # Defining rows to be scraped
        rows = response.xpath('//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]')
        for row in rows:
            #getting the link to each state
            state = row.xpath('.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]/li[1]/a/@href').extract_first()

            item = LawnItem()
            item['state'] = state

            #Following the link  
            yield scrapy.Request(state,
                                 callback=self.parse_detail,
                                 meta={'item': item})
    # Getting detail insithe each link
    def parse_detail(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']

        name = response.xpath('.//*[@id="container"]/div[3]/div/div/div/h2/u/text()').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if your `row.xpath()` result produced a result:

```
state = row.xpath('.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]/li[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
```

`state` is `None`, and so you get that exception.

You will *always* get `None` here, as there are no tags nested inside the `<ul id="horizontal-list">` tag.  The expression `.//` can only find child tags of the `<ul>` tag, not the tag itself!

At best you can use `row.xpath('.//li[1]/a/@href')` to get a nested `<a href>` tag, but that can still can produce `None` if there are no `<li>` tags or if the first `<li>` tag doesn't have a `<a>` tag nested directly in it, or if that tag doesn't have a `href` attribute.

Next, there is just a **single** `<ul id="horizontal-list">` tag, so your `for row in rows:` loop will only execute once.

If you want to find *all* the links under the `<ul>` *just select those directly*:

```
# find all <a href> elements inside <ul id="horizontal-list"><li> elements
# and take the href values.
links = response.xpath('//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]/li//a/@href')
for link in links:
    item = LawnItem()
    item['state'] = link.get()
    yield scrapy.Request(
        link,
        callback=self.parse_detail,
        meta={'item': item}
    )
```

Remember that you can always use [`scrapy shell <url>`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#std:command-shell) to try out expressions; scrapy loads the URL given on the command line for you, and provides you with a `response` object (among other objects):

```
$ bin/scrapy shell --nolog http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/findlandscaper.htm
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10eaab7c0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/findlandscaper.htm>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/findlandscaper.htm>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10eaab4c0>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x10ee4de50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> links = response.xpath('//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]/li//a/@href')
>>> len(links)
50
>>> links[0]
<Selector xpath='//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]/li//a/@href' data='http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/statedi'>
>>> links[0].get()
'http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/statedirectory.php?state=Alabama'
>>> links[-1].get()
'http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/statedirectory.php?state=Wyoming'
```

Compare this with your own expressions:

```
>>> rows = response.xpath('//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]')
>>> len(rows)
1
>>> rows[0]
<Selector xpath='//ul[@id="horizontal-list"]' data='<ul id="horizontal-list">\n\t\t\n<li><a href'>
>>> rows[0].xpath('.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]/li[1]/a/@href')
[]
>>> rows[0].xpath('.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]/li[1]/a/@href').extract_first() is None
True
```

You got an empty result, so `.extract_first()` gives you `None`, because `.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]` can't find anything; you can't find the same element as a child element again, use `'.'` to find the 'current' elment instead:

```
>>> rows[0].xpath('.//*[@id="horizontal-list"]')
[]
>>> rows[0].xpath('.')
[<Selector xpath='.' data='<ul id="horizontal-list">\n\t\t\n<li><a href'>]
>>> rows[0].xpath('.//li[1]/a/@href')
[<Selector xpath='.//li[1]/a/@href' data='http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/statedi'>]
>>> rows[0].xpath('.//li[1]/a/@href').get()
'http://www.lawncaredirectory.com/statedirectory.php?state=Alabama'
```

But by using `li[1]` you only get a single element, anyway.